# Выравнивание главного блока по центру страницы

Tags: html, javascript, css

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой есть див блок:

```
<div class="cont_main" style="margin: 0px auto;position: relative;display: block;width: 980px; border:1px solid #CCC; min-height:110%; margin-top:60px;"></div>
```

На моем мониторе все нормально,но если вдруг монитор увеличивается (разрешение) то главный блок перестает находиться по центру экрана,подскажите как можно сделать так что бы он постоянно находился по центру(Пс блок идет как главный в него вложено довольно много других блоков).Если есть какой нибудь туториал то подскажите пожалуйста,скиньте пример.(Что то похожее используется на facebook с главным блоком,когда при увелич. разрешения блок остается по центру при маленьком разрешении так же по центру.)Заранее спасибо.

### **Уточнение!**

---

Выравнивание центрального блока должно произойти между левой частью экрана и фиксированным блоком в левой части

```
 <div class="d1"></div> 
.d1 {
border-top: 0;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #494949;
line-height: 42px;
width: 211px;
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1001;
```

Comment: По центру и по вертикали и по горизонтали? И высота у него какая должна быть? Это чтоб по вертикали центровать

Comment: по горизонтали высотка минимальная 110%

Comment: может ты имеешь ввиду резиновый блок по центру?

Comment: Нет у его дина только резиновая остальное нет,надо просто что бы блок всегда находился по центру страницы

Comment: Во-первых, высота не по горизонтали, по вертикали, наверно)
Во-вторых, задайте фиксированную высоту, иначе на каждом разрешении высота у вас будет пересчитываться и вы точно не выровните. Если мы говорим о том, чтоб у вас по вертикали было одинаковое расстояние и сверху и снизу, то проще всего их задать. Либо фиксировано `margin-top/bottom:60px`, либо в процентах `margin-top/bottom:15%;`

Comment: надо блок выровнять по горизонтали,ширина фиксированная пробовал методом margin:0 auto; но не помогла блок стал прижат к левой части экрана.

Comment: В каком браузере, у меня все нормально выравнивается?)

Comment: chrome разрешение 1366*768 все нормально но при увеличении разрешение монитор более больше блок прижат к левой части экрана с настройками margin:0 auto;Ps справа в отличии от крайнего центрального блока есть второстепенный фиксированный прижатый блок с высотой 100% и шириной 250 px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот блок, который нужно центровать относительно экрана, примени такой стиль:

```
/* center start */

.center {

        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left:-50px;
        margin-top:-50px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        }
/* center end*/
```

Теперь поясню, что такое  `-50px` - это ровно половина размера твоего блока. Если будет, например, `300px`, то `-150px`.